# Interfaces in Groovy

Tags: grails, interface, groovy, dns

I'm about to start a social web app project.

While i was designing classes , i decided to define interfaces like "commentable" or "likeable" to use them when needed.

Yet i couldn't figure it out how to implement it in Groovy, that i am in the learning phase.

The Example below is from the Groovy documentation,

```
 interface X
{ void f(); void g(int n); void h(String s, int n); }

x = [ f: {println "f called"} ] as X
x.f()
//x.g()    // NPE here
```

Say this is one of my interfaces , and I want to use a Class called B to implement this interface ..

shall I just say B as X , in the related controller?

How to do it in domain layer? If a class Z is, lets say "commentable" , shall i just make a domain class called Comment and say Z hasMany Comment? and use the interface in the controller layer?

What is the Groovy way to do this correctly? I'm bit confused and a little clarification would be really nice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The example you show is not the right one to use when implementing your own interfaces. That's a convenient way to only partially implement an interface. In this example only the `f` method is implemented, so the others fail as you saw. This is useful for testing when you have a large interface but only call a few methods in the class under test, so you don't need to implement the whole interface.

You implement interfaces in Groovy just like in Java:

```
interface Math {
   int add(int a, int b)

   int multiply(int a, int b)
}

class SimpleMathImpl implements Math {
   int add(int a, int b) {
      a + b
   }

   int multiply(int a, int b) {
      a * b
   }
}
```

Comment: are you sure about that i didnt see any single examples like this even not sure implements keyword exists Groovy

Comment: so regarding the design question if i can define an interface just like in Java , implementing it in the Controller and using hasMany in domain would be a correct thing to do?

Comment: There's little benefit in using interfaces in Groovy (or Grails) since you can call whatever method you want - Groovy supports "duck typing". Some plugins use them but really more as "marker" interfaces with no methods, and they're just used to classify types so you can check for "instanceof MyInterface" and act accordingly. But other than that there's really no reason to use interfaces.

Comment: Regarding your "implements" question - nearly all Java code is valid Groovy code, so of course Groovy supports the `implements` keyword. You might want to get a copy of Venkat Subramaniam's "Programming Groovy" - it's very good and is the most recently published Groovy book. "Groovy in Action" is the classic but is somewhat dated, although the 2nd edition is available in an early access edition at http://www.manning.com/koenig2/

Comment: @BurtBeckwith - if you are doing a mixed Java and Groovy project, it could be useful to indicate the interface information to the Java parts of the project, even if Groovy callers don't need it.